# Angular - Http get works without async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I need to get only single item, so I used ngIf instead ngFor in template.

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="item | async">
    Id {{ item.id }}
    Number {{ item.number }}
</div>
```

Service:

```
get(id: number): Observable<Response> {
return this.http
  .get(`myApi/id`)
  .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Component:

```
export class DetailItemPage {
 private item: Observable<Object>;

 ngOnInit(){
  this.getItem(6994);
 }

getItem(id){
  this.itemProvider.get(id).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.item = res;
       console.log(this.item);
     });
  }

}
```

In the console log I see the object correctly.

With that example, I get error:

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

But if I remove the async pipe, WORKS. I can see the item id and number.
Why? What I am doing wrong?

PS: I used Angular 4.1.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `async` pipe expects a `Promise` or `Observable`. In your case you add a normal `Object`. This is not what the pipe wants, and so it throws an error. You do not have to use the async pipe here.

You can however use it like this:

```
export class DetailItemPage {
   private item: Observable<Object>;

   ngOnInit(){
     this.getItem(6994);
   }

   getItem(id){
      this.item = this.itemProvider.get(id);
   }
}
```

In this case the `item` is really an `Observable`, and your pipe will be very happy. Just know that using `Observable<Object>` as type definition for your field value does not guarantee that you will actually have an `Observable<Object>` in there. Because the `http` call returns with an `any`, the compiler still believes all is good in the hood, even though it really wasn't.

Comment: So it's okay not to use the async pipe there? Despite being an http call?

Comment: indeed, thats okay

Answer (score 1):

the async pipe is for dealing with `Promise` and `Observable` objects, item is not an observable, but the data contained in the response as you assing `item` inside your `subscribe` callback.

that would work if you do this :

```
getItem(id){
  this.item=this.itemProvider.get(id);
}
```